# Java: else statement still executing even if if statement is true

Tags: java

there currently doing an IT assessment at school and have come into a problem with my else statement.

Code:

```
         if (SPEED.getPower() + HEALTH.getPower() + POWER.getPower() == 100);{
         System.out.println("********");
         System.out.println("Your battleBots name is "+ name11.getName());
         System.out.println("Your battleBots Health stat is "+HEALTH.getHealth());
         System.out.println("Your battleBots Power stat is "+POWER.getPower());
         System.out.println("Your battleBots Speed stat is "+SPEED.getSpeed());
         System.out.println("********");}
         Else :
         {
            System.out.println("your stat total did not equal a total of 100 (over or under), this means your stats will be set to 40/30/30");
            HEALTH.setHealth(40);
            SPEED.setSpeed(30);
            POWER.setPower(30);
         }
```

this also uses a second blueprint as my school calls it for the assessment.

Code:

```
package BattleBots;

public class BattleBotsBlueprint {


        private double health;
        private double power;
        private double speed;
        private String name1;
        

        public void setHealth(double h)
        {   health = h;}
        public void setName(String n)
        {   name1 = n;}
        
        public void setPower(double p)
        {   power = p;}
        
        public void setSpeed(double s)
        {   speed = s;}
        
        public double getPower()
        {   return power;}
        public String getName()
        {   return name1;}
        
        public double getHealth()
        {   return health;}
        
        public double getSpeed()
        {   return speed;}
        
        
        }
```

anyways why is the else statement being used even though the if statement is true?

Comment: There is a semicolon after your first if statement. Also this is not the proper syntax to write an `else`

Comment: That's invalid code. You don't write `Else: ` in Java, and if you use the correct way of writing it, the problem with the semicolon will be shown up.

Comment: "*`Else :`*" - This is not an [`else` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html). This is a [label](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are using ';' incorrectly at the of of the `if` statement.
Also at the else you don't need ':'

Comment: This will not compile.

Comment: now if just underlines the Else in red (using ide eclipse)?

Comment: write else with small 'e', doe's it solve the problem?